# How to position a text inside a rotated div box

Tags: css, css-shapes

Like this

[image]

Should be centered too.

```
.diamond {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
    transform: rotate(45deg);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the content back the other way.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.diamond {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 25px;
}
.diamond p {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond">
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, I'm stupid. I was trying to do this with rotating and relative positioning, good solution @Paulie_D.

Comment: Oh nice! That idea did cross my mind but I thought there must be a more natural way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a pseudo element for this.
Then i only need to apply one rotation.
That rotation is only on a single element.

```css
.mid-angle {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.mid-angle:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mid-angle">Hello</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice idea too. How is the browser support for pseudo elements? It's not newer than the `transform` we used, is it?